# Javascript functions with a parameter that have a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

please explain to me how this works. I'm new to nodejs and the way they set up their code is very complicated to me to properly understand..

I split the code that I don't understand into little snippets. You can find the whole code below.

```
callback(function() {
  results.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  next();
});
```

I don't understand the above snippet. It seems like this anonymous function becomes the next argument of the series anon function? Will the code in the anon function arguments execute?

```
function(next) { async(1, next); }
```

Which will execute first? The async function execution in the series functions or the next parameter execution?

**Here I attached the full code:**

```
function series(callbacks, last) {
  var results = [];
  function next() {
    var callback = callbacks.shift();
    if(callback) {
      callback(function() {
        results.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        next();
      });
    } else {
      last(results);
    }
  }
  next();
}

function async(arg, callback) {
  var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1) * 100;
  console.log('async with \''+arg+'\', return in '+delay+' ms');
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(arg*2);
  }, delay);
}

function final(results) {
  console.log('Done', results);
}

series([
  function(next) { async(1, next); },
  function(next) { async(2, next); },
  function(next) { async(3, next); },
  function(next) { async(4, next); },
  function(next) { async(5, next); },
  function(next) { async(6, next); }
], final);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, know that in JavaScript, functions can be passed as parameters to other functions. This is very different than passing the value returned from another function. Take this simple example:

```
function A() {
    alert("In A"); 
}

function B(fn) {
    alert("In B");
    fn(); 
}

B(A);   // alerts "In B", then "In A".

B(A()); // alerts "In A", then "In B", 
        // (then errors because the return value from A is undefined, 
        // and thus cannot be invoked.)
```

So, to follow your code example from beginning to end, here's how it goes...

1. `series` is a function that takes an array of functions (`callbacks`) and one more function (`last`) as parameters. It gets invoked first.
2. Within `series`, a function named `next` is defined (not to be confused with the parameter to each of the callback functions named `next`). The function `next` is invoked.
3. Within `next`, a variable named `callback` is defined. It's value is one of functions from the `callbacks` array in turn. The function stored in the `callback` variable gets invoked with an anonymous function.
4. Within `callback`, the `async` function is invoked. The same anonymous function from step 3 is passed to `async`. It's now called `next`, but this has nothing much to do with the `next` function defined in `series`.
5. Within `async`, some calculations are done and eventually the anonymous function is invoked (via `setTimeout`). It's called `callback` within the `async` function.
6. Within the anonymous function, some values are pushed onto the `results` array, and `next` is invoked. This is the `next` function defined in `series`.
7. Repeat steps 3 through 6 until all the functions within `callbacks` have been invoked and then the function in the parameter `last` (`final`) is invoked.

Clear as mud, right?

Comment: hello, sorry for the late reply. I'm trying to wrap my mind through this code. But I have one more question since this is the most confusing part of the code: In the sample code that you provided, the B(A()) alerts In A first then In B. So in my code, the callback(function() { results..; next(); }) will execute first before async?

Comment: Because in your steps by steps guide, the anon function in callback() was in step 6. so async executed first

Comment: maybe i don't understand the idea of callbacks. thanks for answering my question in a clear manner. i will be researching callbacks first then maybe this my confusion will be answered. thank you.

Comment: Yes, `async` was invoked first, because the anonymous function was passed into it as an argument. The anonymous function is invoked *within* `async`. You can kinda think of functions as being dormant until they are invoked. Even though they may be passed around to multiple different other functions, they don't execute until the `()` is used on them, i.e. they are invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The series function takes a lists of functions to execute. Each of this functions must take a single parameter that needs to be a function, a callback. `series` uses that callback to know that a function finished its async work.

Here's a step by step of what `series` does:

1. Take a list of functions and a single callback named `last`
2. Create a `results` array where we'll store the results of all those functions
3. Pick the first item in the list and remove from the list
4. If the item is not a function (the list is empty):

   1. Call `last` with the `results` array
   2. Stop. We're done
5. If the item is a function call it and pass it a new callback that lets us know when it's done
6. Once the function is done doing its async work it should call the callback with any number of parameters. Store those parameters in the `results` array
7. Go to 3

Basically, it's a recursive function that waits until a process is done between each step. The results will be that each function you pass it in its `callbacks` list will be called sequentially, each after the previous finished doing its work.

Don't be discouraged. Async code is hard even for seasoned programmers.

Comment: Thanks for your simple explanation. Yes, async is very new to me. But to tell you honestly im not really good in programming so maybe thats the reason. :)